# Remove tomcat ROOT directory

Tags: tomcat

Is it possible to remove the Tomcat ROOT directory? We have several applications running on a Tomcat instance. I was asked to clean the webapps directory up and remove any unused folders. I removed
manager, host-manager, docs and examples.

Everything is fine, as I expected. I looked at the ROOT folder and there are images, a couple of jsp pages and a WEB-INF directory. None of these are used by our applications, so I removed the ROOT directory. Now the server hangs on startup and my applications don't start. Can the ROOT directory be removed? It appears that according to the Apache docs it is optional:

> "The ROOT web application presents a very low security risk but it does include the version of Tomcat that is being used. The ROOT web application should normally be removed from a publicly accessible Tomcat instance, not for security reasons, but so that a more appropriate default page is shown to users."

I tried leaving just an empty ROOT directory, but it still hangs. Is there a configuration that I'm missing somewhere that could be looking for the ROOT directory?

Tomcat version 8.5.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many Tomcat components assume that an `org.apache.catalina.Context` is available for each request. If you delete the `ROOT` application, this won't be true for all URI paths and `NullPointerException`s will follow. This certainly happens with the `RewriteValve`, but may apply to other components.

Therefore it is better to have a `ROOT` application, but it can also be an **empty** directory.

Whether this behaviour of Tomcat components is a *bug* or not is susceptible to discussion. Personally I consider a missing `ROOT` context as a *misconfiguration*, but you can file a *bug report* if you think otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, Piotr, very helpful information